# Find a hexadecimal string in a file knowing a memory offset and string length

Tags: c, string, memory-management, hex

Good morning stackoverflow !

I'm trying to extract from a binary file a hexadecimal string. I can't find this string directly, but I know that the string is 0x30 long and begins 0x10 after a known hex string.

So here is my code

```
 FILE *f = NULL;
    unsigned char *buffer = NULL;
    unsigned long fileLen;

    unsigned char known_string[] = {0x45, 0x45, 0x45, 0x45};


printf("Opening file...\n");  
    f = fopen(argv[1], "rb");

    if (!f) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open %s\n", argv[1]);
        return -1;
    }

// Get the length
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    fileLen=ftell(f);

    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);

// Allocate memory
    buffer=malloc(fileLen);

    if (!buffer)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory error!\n");
        fclose(f);
        return -1;
    }

// File to buffer

fread(buffer, fileLen, 1, f);
    fclose(f);

printf("Buffer starts: %p\n", &buffer[0]);
printf("Buffer ends: %p\n", &buffer[fileLen]);

// Determines offset of known_string

char *p = memmem(buffer, fileLen, bytes, 4);
if (!p) {
    return -1;
} else {

  printf(" General offset: %x\n", p);    
}

  free(buffer);
```

So I get the general offset of the known string but I need to get the one relative to the file. I'm a bit stuck at this step. I think I must do something like p - &buffer[0], but p and &buffer[0] are not of the same type, and p is not even the real offset (678987 instead of 10678987 e.g). Then in the case I got the relative offset, how could I find the unknown string ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're only interested in the pointer address, not the data it points to, you may just as well use void *, and you don't have to do &buffer[0], it's not an array.

```
unsigned long off_to_string = 0x10 + 4 + ((void *)p) - ((void *)buffer);
```

I add 0x10 + 4 to skip the found hex byte sequence and the bytes up to the searched for string.

Comment: You can't do pointer arithmetic with `void *` in standard C - that's a GNU C extension.

Comment: @caf, Ok, thanks. I don't keep all standards in my head :)
It's easy to cast to another type, as you've shown.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is use `unsigned char *` for the type of `p` - then you can just subtract:

```
unsigned char *p = memmem(buffer, fileLen, bytes, 4);

if (!p) {
    return -1;
} else {
  printf(" General offset: %p\n", p);    
  printf(" Offset within file: %llx\n", (unsigned long long)(p - buffer));
}
```